# All combinations of 2-value variables

Tags: scala, combinatorics, library, type-safety

### Introduction

This code was part of one of my projects where it was used to generate boolean input values for truth tables. I have since generalized it for combinations of variables with only 2 values, and added a dash of general Scala-isms. This has been unit-tested with ScalaTest, and has proper documentation.

I rewrote my original code which used bitmasking and shifts because I thought it was too "magical", i.e., difficult to understand at first glance. The bitmasking method also does not give a proper ordering of the values as I would have liked it, which this method does.

This also embodies the concept of a multi-line expression-bodied method.

### Notes

My IDE (IntelliJ Idea) recommends not using superfluous parentheses, but I leave them in for clarity.

I would like reviews on any and all aspects of the code and documentation, including but not limited to performance (not really important over clarity to me here, otherwise I'd have used the bitmasking version instead), clarity and idiomatic nature of the code.

#### Running

Just copy into a file with extension `.scala` and run it in the Scala REPL as a script. Example usage:

```
allCombinations(4, true, false) // duplicates the use case I had in my project.
```

(Run the above in the REPL after the script as beem loaded (`scala <file name>.scala`, or put it at the bottom of the file `<file name>.scala`)

---

### Code

```
/**
    * Generates all possible distinct combinations of `n` variables which have only 2 values,
    * `value` and `alternativeValue`.
    *
    * @param n                the number of variables to generate combinations for
    * @param value            one possible value for a variable
    * @param alternativeValue the other possible value for a variable
    * @return all possible distinct combinations of `n` booleans
    */
def allCombinations[T](n: Int, value: T, alternativeValue: T): Seq[Seq[T]] = {
    for (i <- 0 to n) yield {
      // Make the first i values true and the rest false,
      // and then take all their permutations.
      // This gives us all the required combinations.
      (Seq.tabulate(n)(x => 
                       if (x < i) value 
                       else alternativeValue)
       ).permutations
    } // flatten 1 level into a 1-deep list
}.flatten
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is the function named `allCombinations`?  The "all" seems superfluous.  Also, it's actually returning *permutations* rather than combinations, so the second half isn't really accurate either.  I suggest naming it something else entirely, though: `product`, based on the [function in Python's `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) that does something similar.  As for the first parameter, I find `dims` (or `dimensions`) to be more descriptive than `n`.

Why limit yourself to two possible values?  Why not also support a tri-state, for example?  You could make `values` variadic.  As a bonus, you wouldn't have to manually toggle between `value` and `alternativeValue`; you could just use normal iteration tools like `.map`.

```
def product[T](dims: Int, values: T*): Seq[Seq[T]] = {
  dims match {
    case 0 => Seq()
    case 1 => values.map(Seq(_))
    case _ => {
      val lesserProduct = product(dims - 1, values:_*)
      values.flatMap(v => lesserProduct.map(_.+:(v)))
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the ordering convention is different from yours; i.e. `product(4, false, true)` is equivalent to `allCombinations(4, true, false)`.  I don't consider that to be a drawback.

Comment: This is not tail-recursive. Might cause a performance hit or stack overflows with higher dimensions; otherwise good

Comment: Plus, it looks horrible. ;). But that's life in Scala!

Comment: How many dimensions could you realistically expect, though?

Comment: In my humble opinion, it looks less horrible than yours. =)

Comment: Also, have you confirmed that this produces the same order of results as mine?

Comment: You could use operator notation for the last `.map`; also, as a library designer, one should always mistrust users to a healthy extent - I guess we should really account for 7000+ dimensions of we go down this route.

Comment: If you reverse the arguments, then the output is in the same order. Alternatively, if you keep the same arguments, then the output is reversed.

Comment: OK. I've accepted your answer for the time being. :). Maybe I'll post an improved version later.